# Optimal offline memory allocation algorithm

Tags: algorithm

I am implementing a system in which the memory could be allocated in an offline manner, i.e. all allocation time, size and deallocation time are known beforehand, and I just need to figure out a static allocation that minimizes peak memory usage.

Google does not help much; most of the results are about dynamic allocators used in various systems. I heard that this problem is NP-Hard, but did not find good reference. I only find that memory insertion and compaction problem is NP-Hard (http://epubs.siam.org/doi/pdf/10.1137/0213037 ), but it seems not equivalent to my situation.

So is there an optimal algorithm in polynomial time, or any good sub-optimal algorithms? Time complexity is not a major concern, as long it could finish in several seconds for thousands of allocations on a multi-core system (maybe O(n^4) is acceptable).

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called the offline dynamic storage allocation problem. Check out the papers cited by https://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/S0097539703423941 for a good review of the literature.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out! It is exactly what I was looking for. In fact the problem scale turned out to be very large and time complexity was important. I came up with a quasilinear algorithm, which uses best fit allowing moving allocated intervals to decide the relative order of boxes. This algorithm is used in a deep learning framework, which happened to be [open sourced](https://github.com/MegEngine/MegEngine/blob/f91881ffdc051ab49314b1bd12c4a07a862dc9c6/src/core/impl/graph/var_node_mem_mgr/static_mem_alloc/pushdown.cpp) recently. It works well in practice (usually <= 1.1LOAD).

Answer (score 0):

This has parallels with [Filling bins with an equal size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27338915/filling-bins-with-an-equal-size) question. In particular you can check the Bin packing problem http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem and the approximate greedy algorithm mentioned therein.

Answer (score 0):

It is close to the register allocation problem solved by compilers. You can model register allocation as a graph colouring problem (NP complete). However, for register allocation, it is simpler because all registers are equal. For memory allocation if you want a chunk of memory of a particular size, that memory needs to be contiguous.

With a little tweaking of the graph colouring problem (colours turn into numbers, plus constraints about sequential numbers) you can reframe the problem. I believe it should still be NP complete.

For good polynomial time algorithms, I would be inpsired by register allocation algorithms.